# Strings in java

Tags: java, string

i'm trying to create a string which i want to have exaclty this form:

```
      <atom:link rel="name" type="html" href="http://www/data/name/1"/>
```

I'm trying this:

```
     String astring = "<atom:link rel="+"name"+" "+"type="+"html"+" "+"href="+"http://www/data/name/"+id+"/>"
```

And i take this:

```
&lt;atom:link rel=name type=html href=http://www/data/name/1/&gt;
```

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

double quotes must be escaped with a backslash inside a String literal:

```
String astring = "<atom:link rel=\"name\" type=\"html\" href=\"http://www/data/name/1\"/>";
```

Answer (score 2):

have a look at  [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String astring = "<atom:link rel="+"\"name\""+" "+"type="+"\"html\""+" "+"href="+"\"http://www/data/name/"+id+"\"/>"
```

You need to escape the `"` character in the strings, do it by preceding it with a backslash: `\"`

Answer (score 0):

No offense, but it seems like you haven't google much or tried to understand the root problem, which is *escaping*. Since this is a foudamental concept for data formats and programming, here is [the page about escape characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in wikipedia.

You should then investigate for yoursefl the notion of escaping in the context of (1) java string, and (2) xml.

Answer (score 0):

What is exactly your problem?
missing double quote? or escaped < > ?

For missing double quote, it is just because you haven't put any double quote in the string.  Please do something like `"rel=\"name\""`

For the latter one, I bet you have put the string as text node and have a XML writer write out the data?  Because in XML, `< >` has to be escaped for proper presentation of a string.  You should not expect to create XML structure by giving a plain string within certain xml node .  Use your XML APIs to properly construct this piece of XML structure.